# Kendo React UI DataTable Filter with same behavior as JQuery Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

In kendo react, the [filter of the grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/filtering/) is a line bellow the header, like the image bellow

[image]

But in the JQuery version the filter is a button that opens a small modal with the filter, like the image bellow

[image]

How can I make Kendo React have a button in the header that opens a modal with the filter instead of a new line with the filter?

Answer (score 2):

The docs wasn't that good, kind of hard to find how to do it, but is [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/columns/column-menu/).

You pass `columnMenu`to `Column` with a component that you want to render and use     `GridColumnMenuSort` and `GridColumnMenuFilter`.